# How to display floating button to bottom center on top of list extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to show a button on top of this [dataView List](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.dataview.List.html) from Extjs [Modern Toolkit]?

The goal is to have similar functionality like a floating action button.